# How come SCNTechnique doesn't have a .library property like SCNProgram?

Tags: scenekit, scntechnique

I'm working on a SceneKit project and I'm using metal to do the rendering. I wanted to apply post-processing to my scene using SCNTechnique, but SCNTechnique requires that the metal shader files need to be located at the default metal library location.
This is problematic because my program has a custom bundle location where all the resources are located, and I cannot access the default location.
When I run my code, SceneKit complains that it "can't find the library without a path" meaning that it didn't find any shaders in the default location (because I can't put them there). Moreso, it doesn't seem like Metal can be embedded in a string literal like OpenGL.
 Oddly, SCNProgram has a library property, so it works since I can set this property to a default library that points to my program's correct bundle and contains all the shaders. However, SCNProgram doesn't support post-processing, only geometry and materials.

Can someone shed some light on this issue?